# Multipage table using tcolorbox and tabularx

Tags: tabularx, tcolorbox

Good day, Sirs and Madams!

I am experiencing issues while composing a big table over several pages. I'd like to use *tcolorbox* in combination with *tabularx*. Unfortunately, this does not work out as expected.

It would be great if someone could help me out how to achieve a table using the stated design that stretches over several pages.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\tcbset{ before=,
            after=\hfil,
            size=small,
            fonttitle=\bfseries\normalsize, 
            fontupper=\small, 
            fontlower=\small, 
            center title}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx*={
\arrayrulewidth 0.5mm}{X|X|X},title=Test]
\emph{A} & \emph{B} & \emph{C}
\\\hline
A & B & C \\
\blindtext[150] & \blindtext[150] & \blindtext[150] \\
\hline
\end{tcolorbox}
\caption{Test}
\label{fig:Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any help or hints are well appreciated.

I've tried using the `[breakable]` option from `\tcbuselibrary{breakable}` but wihtout any luck.

Comment: you need  longtable or ltxtable packages

Comment: A `tabularx` can't be split across pages.

Comment: as egreg says you can not use tabularx, but there is no need to use it anyway if the array preamble is `{X|X|X}` in your real example as you know the width in advance each column is `p{\dimexpr(\linewidth-2\arrayrulewidth-6\tabcolsep).3\relax}`

Comment: there is also the problem of figure environnement

Comment: And bad news is... `tcolorbox` has no long table or `ltxtable` options (unless Thomas does some thing in the up coming versions.)

Comment: @HarishKumar It's possible to insert a `longtable` into a breakable `tcolorbox` without too much problems. But one cannot have `longtable` headings on the broken partial tables. If one can live without that nice `longtable` feature, it works.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm ah you're here, can you fix my answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added an answer with some modifications. :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Oh!, but the interface like the one for tabularx was what I was referring to. Now it is put mostly as a direct content. And the repeating headings too :-) Is there any plan to include them? It will be great.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Can we not overlay the headings and repeat them?

Comment: @HarishKumar Yes, I think so. With fixed-size columns it should be possible to simulate the repeated headings. If the width of the columns is not fixed, this will not work or would have to be adapted to each change of content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my addition to David Carlisle's answer. I sorted things a little bit different and added some options which might be useful. Especially, the right edge problem is resolved and the caption put into the title.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl,lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  breakable=true,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  size=small,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\normalsize,
  fontupper=\small,
  fontlower=\small,
  center title,
  title={\captionsetup{skip=0pt}\captionof{table}{Test}},
  colbacktitle=blue!10,
  colframe=blue!50!black,
  colback=yellow!10,
  label=fig:Test
  ]
\def\LTpre{0pt}%
\begin{longtable}{
@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
>{\raggedright}p{.3\linewidth}|
>{\raggedright}p{.3\linewidth}|
>{\raggedright}p{.3\linewidth}
@{}}
\emph{A} & \emph{B} & \emph{C}\tabularnewline\hline
A & B & C \tabularnewline
\blindtext[1] & \blindtext[1] & \blindtext[1] \tabularnewline
\blindtext[1] & \blindtext[1] & \blindtext[1] \tabularnewline
\blindtext[1] & \blindtext[1] & \blindtext[1] \tabularnewline
\blindtext[1] & \blindtext[1] & \blindtext[1] \tabularnewline
\blindtext[1] & \blindtext[1] & \blindtext[1] \tabularnewline
\blindtext[1] & \blindtext[1] & \blindtext[1] \tabularnewline
\blindtext[1] & \blindtext[1] & \blindtext[1] \tabularnewline
\blindtext[1] & \blindtext[1] & \blindtext[1] \tabularnewline
\end{longtable}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The example looks splendid when using the `geometry` option with a `margin` of 2cm but in combination with the `lncs` template the table look weird. Do you have any advice on how to beautify the table when using `lncs`?

Comment: @FloatingPointZilch I'm no sure what weird means here. I just tried the Springer `llncs` class, but saw no specific problem (?).